# Converting unix timestamp to Milliseconds in luxon.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timestamp, luxon

I have string data in the format "hh:mm" e.g. 05:00. I want it in Milliseconds e.g 1800000

`console.log(DateTime.fromISO("05:00")` and i get the following output: 1654574400000 but what i want it in seconds so i can compare it against a different value. I have tried putting .toMillis() at the end
`console.log(DateTime("05:00")).toMillis();`
and it comes back with *"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Class constructor DateTime cannot be invoked without 'new'".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a time is passed to *fromISO*, the current date is used. To get the time in milliseconds, parse it to a *DateTime* and subtract a *DateTime* for the start of the day, e.g.

```js
let DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

function timeToMs(time) {
  let then = DateTime.fromISO(time);
  let now = DateTime.fromISO("00:00");
  return then - now;
}

console.log(timeToMs('05:00'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.4.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use plain JS:

```js
function timeToMS(time) {
  let [h, m, s, ms] = time.split(/\D/);
  return h*3.6e6 + (m||0)*6e4 + (s||0)*1e3 + (ms||0)*1;
}

console.log(timeToMS('05:00'));
console.log(timeToMS('01:01:01.001'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse `"05:00"` as a [`Duration`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#duration), using [`Duration.fromISOTime`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#durationfromisotime) that:

> Create a Duration from an ISO 8601 time string.

and then display its value using [`as(unit)`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#durationas):

> Return the length of the duration in the specified unit.

Example:

```js
const Duration = luxon.Duration;
console.log(Duration.fromISOTime('05:00').as('milliseconds'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.4.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```